How to view map distortions with different SRIDs in QGIS?
I have a coast map in PostGIS table with the SRID 4326 and would like to visualize how map is distorted using different projections. I made two tables projected source data to UTM and Lambert and added them as layers to a QGIS project. But both maps look absolutely the same even on a large scale. What did I miss?
Some queries I used:
1)
-- creating UTM zone 40 (32640) data from WGS84
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS utm_coast;
CREATE TABLE utm_coast (id int, geom Geometry(MULTILINESTRING));
INSERT INTO utm_coast (id, geom) SELECT id, ST_transform(geom,32640) FROM wgs84_coast;




-- Creating custom lambert 2p
DELETE FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srid=912345;
INSERT INTO spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, srtext, proj4text)
VALUES (912345, 'custom_lambert2p', 912345, 
        'PROJCRS["unknown",BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",DATUM["Unknown based on WGS 84 ellipsoid",ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",7030]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8901]]],CONVERSION["unknown",METHOD["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",ID["EPSG",9802]],PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",67.5,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8821]],PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",56.5,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8822]],PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",67.5,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8823]],PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",69.5,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8824]],PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8826]],PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8827]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["(E)",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],AXIS["(N)",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]]]',
        '+proj=lcc +lat_0=67.5 +lon_0=56.5 +lat_1=67.5 +lat_2=69.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs'
       );




-- creating lambert 2p data from WGS84
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lcc2p_coast;
CREATE TABLE lcc2p_coast (id int, geom Geometry(MULTILINESTRING));
INSERT INTO lcc2p_coast (id, geom) SELECT id, ST_transform(geom, 912345) FROM wgs84_coast;

